# How do I get reset button to automatically click apply button in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app with a `reset` that resets filters to a default setting. The goal is that when a user clicks the `reset`, there is a delay of 300 miliseconds and then the `apply` button is automatically clicked, in other to reset the filters. Right now the `reset` button resets the filters once it is clicked, however the data output (see data table output) is not being reset until I actually click the `apply` button. See sample code below -

```
# Libraries ----
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

data <- mtcars %>% as_tibble()

# UI ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        pickerInput(
            inputId = "cyl_picker",
            label = "Cylinder",
            choices = unique(data$cyl),
            selected = unique(data$cyl),
            multiple = TRUE
        ),
        
        # * Apply Button ----
        actionButton(
            inputId = "apply", 
            label   = "Apply", 
            icon    = icon(name = "play", lib = "font-awesome")
        ),
        
        # * Reset Button ----
        actionButton(
            inputId = "reset", 
            label   = "Reset", 
            icon    = icon("sync")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        dataTableOutput("test_table")
    )
)


# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Data Setup ----
    data_filtered <- eventReactive(eventExpr = input$apply, valueExpr = {
        
        data %>% 
            filter(cyl %in% input$cyl_picker)
        
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE
    )
    
    # Datatable ----
    output$test_table <- renderDataTable(({data_filtered()}))
    
    # Apply / Reset Reactive ----
        shiny::observeEvent(eventExpr = input$reset, handlerExpr = {

            # * Reset Date Range Input ----
            updatePickerInput(
                session   = getDefaultReactiveDomain(),
                inputId   = "cyl_picker",
                choices   = unique(data$cyl),
                selected  = unique(data$cyl)

            )

           
            # * Reset Button Reactive ---- 
            shinyjs::delay(ms = 300, expr = {
                shinyjs::click(id = "apply")
            })

        })
    
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Again my goal is to reset the data table output once the `reset` button is clicked.

Comment: That is because `data_filtered` is a `eventReactive` object.  Clicking on `reset` will have no impact on it as only `apply` is triggering it.  Change it to a `reactive` object.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few libraries to get this working in this reprex. `shinyjs` and `shinyWidgets`.

You almost have it but in order for shinyjs to work you need to initialize it in the the ui.R.

```
dashboardBody(
        useShinyjs(), # initialize shinyjs
        dataTableOutput("test_table")
    )
```